# If it is possible to set Error message instead of Hint in TextInputLayout?

Tags: java, android

So there is default error message 
[image]

I need move `Error` word on the top instead of `Confirm password*`

[image]

Comment: I think you cannot do it. because you are using textInput layout. If you want to keep error above the edit text you can keep separate text view on top of that.

Comment: @Aleksey pls. elaborate more

Comment: @Aleksey You want to replace Confirm password* with Error text ?

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 added image to discription

Comment: @JaiminModi added image to question